# Add color swatches to Collection page Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am working on debut theme for a while, and I am stuck at a place where I want to show color swatches on the collection page of the store. The problem I am facing right now is that the swatch of particular product doesnt change the image of the same product, instead of that it changes the images of only first product. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.
Please Help out !

Link :https://erin-snow.myshopify.com/collections/all

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any code, I can tell that all of the swatches are related to the first swatch and product image and they shouldn't be.

You need to make it so each color swatch has it's own instance with it's own specific target.